# Check which table has the result in MySQL query, using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following MySQL query to check several tables for any results where the date is within 30 days.

What I want to do is be able to also check which table had the result, not just whether the MySQL query found a result in general.

One of my tables is supplier_bank_details, so if there is a record in this table with a date which is less than 30 days old then I am echoing out bank detail information, otherwise if it's my other table `supplier_invoices` then I want to echo out invoice information.

Here's what I have so far but I am really new to MySQL and struggling a bit. Please could someone show me what I would need to do to get this to work.

```
<?php require_once 'config.php'; ?>

<?php
$tbl_name = 'supplier_bank_details';
$tbl_name2 = 'supplier_invoices;

$query = "select * from $tbl_name, $tbl_name2 WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ORDER BY date DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error() );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

$datetime1 = new DateTime(); // Today's Date/Time
$datetime2 = new DateTime($row['date']);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);


if(mysql_num_rows($tbl_name) > 0) {

$account_number = '****'.substr($row['account_number'], -4);

echo '<div class="contracts_area"><div class="table_header"></div>';
echo '<div class="request"><p>Bank Details Changed</p><p>'.$row['sort_code'].'</p><p>'.$account_number.'</p><p>about '.$interval->format('%d days ago').'</p></div>';
echo '</div>';

}else{

some invoice info here

}else{

echo '<div class="no_activity">No Recent Activity</div>';    
} 

}?>
```

Comment: you are missing a quote on this line: `P $tbl_name2 = 'supplier_invoices;`. Try this: `$tbl_name2 = 'supplier_invoices';`

Comment: Try running an example query in your database proper first (e.g. at your console, or phpMyAdmin). I suspect you need a join between those two tables, at the moment you have the _Cartesian product_, which in most cases is not very useful. This is every row in the first table paired with every row in the second table.

Comment: _Please_, ***Stop using the deprecated `mysql` extension***, [read the red **warning** box on top of every `mysql_*` man page](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect). Learn to use (and love) `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead (the `i` in mysqli stands for improved, that should give you a clue). `PDO` is more widespread and offers a cleaner API. `mysqli` is slightly more powerful, but its api is a right mess. PS: You're calling `mysql_fetch_assoc` ***before*** checking `mysql_num_rows() > 0`, and you're not passing `$result` to the num_rows function...

Comment: @Elias: if that's a copy-n-paste, you may wish to correct it - it's a **red** warning box `:-)`.

Answer (score 0):

Not too elegant, but you can add a constant field to your query, which refers to the table name:

```
select *,"tab1" as tablename from tab1
```

A column, called `tablename` will appear, wit with value of `"tab1"` in each row. It works only if there is least one record in the table.

*Update*: it's more useful, when you join different tables into a single result set.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate queries if the data from both tables doesn't need to be merged together. Have one function to get supplier_bank_details over the last x days, another to get supplier_invoices over the last x days, and then you can handle any logic about what you want to show in PHP.